# PyQt Right click Menu for QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm trying to extend the QComboClass with a right click menu, and offer it an option to set the current index to -1 (clearing the selection). I'm having trouble invoking the context menu or even the right click event.

```
class ComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ComboBox, self).__init__()
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu)

    def showMenu(self, pos):
        menu = QMenu()
        clear_action = menu.addAction("Clear Selection", self.clearSelection)
        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))

    def clearSelection(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(-1)
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your example code works perfectly fine for me. What exactly is the problem? Maybe you should give a more complete example that shows how you are using the class.

Comment: I messed up how I used the class, I had another class from a deprecated module with the same name without this implemented. Which is why the code didn't work. Took a while to realize this! :\

Comment: I know this thread is about a year old, but you really should either choose the `pyqt5` OR `pyqt4` based on which you are using because slots and signal handling is treated differently between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try this,

```
def showMenu(self,event):
    menu = QMenu()
    clear_action = menu.addAction("Clear Selection", self)
    action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
    if action == clear_action:
        self.clearSelection()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMenu



class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel("Ubuntu", self)

        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.combo.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu)
        self.combo.addItem("Ubuntu")
        self.combo.addItem("Mandriva")
        self.combo.addItem("Fedora")
        self.combo.addItem("Red Hat")
        self.combo.addItem("Gentoo")

        self.combo.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl.move(50, 150)

        self.combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QComboBox')
        self.show()

    def showMenu(self,pos):
        menu = QMenu()
        clear_action = menu.addAction("Clear Selection")
        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
        if action == clear_action:
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def onActivated(self, text):

        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.